# Nested list comprehension with split() in python

Tags: python

Long story short, I am trying to work with some crazy data I collected yesterday. A quick nested for loop would do this real easy but right now, I just want to get my nested list comprehension to work. There are a bunch of post on this subject and I am not sure whether it is just me or the because of Friday evening, I can't get it to work. My list comphrension is in format:

```
[ [str(j[0], sanitize(j[1]) for j in i.split(',')] for i in b]
```

where b is `['string, float\t\n', 'string, float\t\n']` or b might be a file object or whatever, doesn't matter a heck lot.

I could simply do something like

```
for i in b:
    out.append(str(j[0]), sanitize(j[1])
```

But, it should be possible by list comprehension. IT SHOULD!!! And, somehow, I am not getting it right.

Now, on to what I have done so far...

```
>>> b
['08:54:55, 0.031250\n', '08:55:57, 0.031250\n']

>>> [i.split(',') for i in b]
[['08:54:55', ' 0.031250\n'], ['08:55:57', ' 0.031250\n']]
```

What I want:

```
[['08:54:55', 0.031250], ['08:55:57', 0.031250]]
```

A multiple list comprehension should do the trick:

Something like:

```
[ [j[0], j[1]] for j in i.split(',') for i in b] # the cleaning/str/float would be something like: str(j[0]), float(j[1])
```

BUT, this is what I get.

```
>>> [ [j[0], j[1]] for j in i.split(',') for i in b]
[['0', '8'], ['0', '8'], [' ', '0'], [' ', '0']]
>>> 
>>> [ [j[1]] for j in i.split(',') for i in b]
[['8'], ['8'], ['0'], ['0']]
```

Any attempt to work on j[0] or j[1] does not pan out.

To figure out what was going on, I did this:

```
>>> [ [ pprint(type(j)) for j in i.split(',')] for i in b]
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
[[None, None], [None, None]]
```

If I don't mess with `j[0]` or `j[1]`,

```
>>> [ [ j for j in i.split(',')] for i in b]
[['08:54:55', ' 0.031250\n'], ['08:55:57', ' 0.031250\n']]
```

The example with `pprint(type(j))` means even if I were to write an external function, it would not do the trick. I would simply be getting an empty list back from the list comprehension.

What am I doing wrong? A lambda might do the trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a second `for` comprehension to extra the `split()`:

```
>>> [[t, sanitize(v)] for i in b for t, v in [i.split(',')]]
[['08:54:55', 0.031250], ['08:55:57', 0.031250]]
```

Comment: That works great. Wrapping i.split(',') in [ ] appears to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

If you write out a proper, working loop:

```
out = []

for i in b:
    j = i.split(',')
    out.append((j[0], sanitize(j[1])))
```

you’ll notice that you need somewhere to store the result of `i.split(',')` to avoid repeating it. This isn’t possible inline in one list comprehension. You can write a function:

```
def convert_thing(thing):
    time, value = thing.split(',')
    return time, sanitize(value)

out = [convert_thing(x) for x in b]
```

or generate intermediate values (don’t do this):

```
out = [(time, sanitize(value)) for time, value in (x.split(',') for x in b)]
# this bit is a generator expression              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: After going through AChampion's answer (see below), it seems that you can actually store result when doing list comprehension. Instead of a simple, a.split(','), I had to do [a.split(',')]. Took me a while to realize that.

Comment: In [24]: [ [j[0], j[1]] for j in [i.split(',')] for i in b]  
Out[24]: [['08:55:57', ' 0.03\n'], ['08:55:57', ' 0.03\n']]  
  
In [25]: [ [j[0], float(j[1])] for j in [i.split(',')] for i in b]  
Out[25]: [['08:55:57', 0.03], ['08:55:57', 0.03]]

Comment: @JamesT: That’s just a two-loop list comprehension, about the same as the snippet in my answer annotated with “don’t do this”. The “don’t do this” applies equally to it.

Comment: ah just realized it. And for reference, the one I typed there does not work - throws a NameError. It was working only because ipython was saving a previous value of i, @AChampion works though.   However, when you said "don't do this", what is the reason? Other then it being exceedingly difficult to read for most part. The time complexity is O(m*n) either way, not sure about the memory. Haven't done actual timeit. Is it more to do with the python programming conventions (preserving simplicity aside) then any inherent issue?

Comment: @JamesT: It’s because it’s hard to read. Anyone who looks at it is going to do a double-take and wonder if that’s what you really meant.